# SailsJS Installable Hook not executing the beforeCreate override

Tags: sails.js

I tried adding an installable hook `sails-hook-myoverride` that looks like this:

```
let carryOn = (values, proceed, previous) => _.isFunction(previous) ? previous(values, proceed) : proceed();
module.exports = function (sails) {
  return {
    initialize: function (cb) {
      sails.after(['hook:orm:loaded'], function () {
        _.each(sails.models, (model) => {
          let previousBeforeUpdate = model.beforeUpdate;
          model.beforeUpdate = function (values, proceed) {
            console.log("myoverride::beforeUpdate", values);
            return carryOn(values, proceed, previousBeforeUpdate);
          };

          let previousBeforeCreate = model.beforeCreate;
          model.beforeCreate = function (values, proceed) {
            console.log("myoverride::beforeCreate", values);
            return carryOn(values, proceed, previousBeforeCreate);
          };
        });

        cb();
      });
    }
  }
};
```

Then in my Test model I added both beforeUpdate and beforeCreate methods:

```
  beforeUpdate: function (values, cb) {
    console.log('Test::beforeUpdate');
    cb();
  },

  beforeCreate: function (values, cb) {
    console.log('Test::beforeCreate');
    cb();
  }
```

And then I called POST on http://localhost:1337/test to test it.

Surprisingly, sails printed only `Test::beforeCreate` and not `myoverride::beforeCreate` as well, as I was hoping it would.

Google did not help and neither did Sails documentation :(
I'm completely lost at the moment...

Answer (score 0):

OK, apparently, `using sails.after(['hook:sockets:loaded'], function () {` works for some reason...